# Broadcom BCM5764M Gig-E kernel driver problem on Server 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom

Just installed Ubuntu Server on a Dell FX160 thin client. Everything seems to be working except for the onboard Gigabit Ethernet. The problem appears to be with a bug in the `tg3` driver.

I can verify that the Ethernet card *does* work fine on Arch Linux (and on Windows if it matters). Arch is using the 4.14 LTS kernels, whereas Ubuntu seems to be using 4.15. So the issue appears perhaps to be with the version of the kernel included in 18 LTS perhaps.

Here is a dump of the kernel messages. Once the link on the card comes up, the following messages appear and the link goes "down". The lights on the card remain lit.

```
[ 1405.685798] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1405.685861] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1405.685925] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 1411.035974] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1411.036018] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp2s0 (tg3): transmit queue 0 timed out
[ 1411.036095] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 0 at /build/linux-SlLHxe/linux-4.15.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:323 dev_watchdog+0x221/0x230
[ 1411.036100] Modules linked in: joydev input_leds mcs7830 usbnet mii shpchp dcdbas coretemp serio_raw mac_hid sch_fq_codel ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid tg3 ptp ahci pps_core psmouse libahci sis_agp
[ 1411.036211] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu
[ 1411.036214] Hardware name: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 160                 /0H7TGR, BIOS A06 05/21/2010
[ 1411.036222] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x221/0x230
[ 1411.036227] RSP: 0018:ffff8ee07dc83e58 EFLAGS: 00010286
[ 1411.036233] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1411.036237] RDX: 0000000000040400 RSI: 00000000000000f6 RDI: 0000000000000300
[ 1411.036241] RBP: ffff8ee07dc83e88 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 000000000000024e
[ 1411.036245] R10: ffff8ee07dc83ee0 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000005
[ 1411.036249] R13: ffff8ee034452000 R14: ffff8ee034452478 R15: ffff8ee07a9de580
[ 1411.036254] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8ee07dc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1411.036257] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1411.036260] CR2: 000055560fcc6ac8 CR3: 00000000338c4000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
[ 1411.036264] Call Trace:
[ 1411.036272]  <IRQ>
[ 1411.036290]  ? dev_deactivate_queue.constprop.33+0x60/0x60
[ 1411.036303]  call_timer_fn+0x30/0x130
[ 1411.036312]  run_timer_softirq+0x3fb/0x450
[ 1411.036321]  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xa0
[ 1411.036332]  ? lapic_next_event+0x20/0x30
[ 1411.036341]  __do_softirq+0xe4/0x2bb
[ 1411.036352]  irq_exit+0xb8/0xc0
[ 1411.036360]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x79/0x130
[ 1411.036368]  apic_timer_interrupt+0x84/0x90
[ 1411.036373]  </IRQ>
[ 1411.036383] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xa7/0x2f0
[ 1411.036387] RSP: 0018:ffff9db88037fe68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff11
[ 1411.036394] RAX: ffff8ee07dca2880 RBX: 00000148884bf543 RCX: 000000000000001f
[ 1411.036397] RDX: 00000148884bf543 RSI: fffffff0279aae7e RDI: 0000000000000000
[ 1411.036400] RBP: ffff9db88037fea8 R08: 0000000000002cd2 R09: 0000000000001610
[ 1411.036403] R10: ffff9db88037fe38 R11: 0000000000002b1a R12: ffff8ee07dcac200
[ 1411.036406] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffffffff87d71b58 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 1411.036420]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x97/0x2f0
[ 1411.036430]  cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[ 1411.036440]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
[ 1411.036449]  do_idle+0x18c/0x1f0
[ 1411.036460]  cpu_startup_entry+0x73/0x80
[ 1411.036470]  start_secondary+0x1ab/0x200
[ 1411.036482]  secondary_startup_64+0xa5/0xb0
[ 1411.036490] Code: 38 00 49 63 4e e8 eb 92 4c 89 ef c6 05 77 05 d9 00 01 e8 c3 36 fd ff 89 d9 48 89 c2 4c 89 ee 48 c7 c7 88 85 99 87 e8 ef c6 80 ff <0f> 0b eb c0 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55
[ 1411.036621] ---[ end trace 73f70c7aa19cd52e ]---
[ 1411.036647] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: transmit timed out, resetting
[ 1411.863845] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) took too long to run: 4.108 msecs
[ 1411.863850] perf: interrupt took too long (37705 > 6226), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 5250
[ 1412.741317] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000000: 0x168414e4, 0x00100506, 0x02000010, 0x00000008
[ 1412.741433] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000010: 0xfebf0004, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.741539] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000020: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x02811028
[ 1412.741641] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000030: 0x00000000, 0x00000048, 0x00000000, 0x0000010a
[ 1412.741737] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000040: 0x00f46003, 0xfff4798e, 0xc0034001, 0x64002008
[ 1412.741823] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000050: 0x0081cc05, 0xfee08004, 0x00000000, 0x00004021
[ 1412.741910] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000060: 0x006c5009, 0xfaebf50b, 0xf1000298, 0x76180000
[ 1412.741996] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000070: 0x000010f2, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.742080] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000080: 0x168414e4, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.742172] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000000b0: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x05784100
[ 1412.742271] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000000c0: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0000000e, 0x00020010
[ 1412.742362] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000000d0: 0x00008fa1, 0x00102100, 0x00074c11, 0x10110040
[ 1412.742456] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000000f0: 0x0000001f, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.742544] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000100: 0x13c10001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00062031
[ 1412.742643] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000110: 0x00000000, 0x00002000, 0x000000a0, 0x00000000
[ 1412.742747] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000130: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x16010002
[ 1412.742848] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000150: 0x800000ff, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.742949] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000160: 0x16c10003, 0xfebb0b08, 0xb8ac6fff, 0x00010004
[ 1412.743040] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000170: 0x00000000, 0x0007810e, 0x00000001, 0x2c0c3c0e
[ 1412.743125] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000180: 0x3f062304, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xffffffff
[ 1412.743211] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000200: 0x00000000, 0x04000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.743296] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000260: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x000000c8
[ 1412.743380] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000300: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.743471] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000310: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.743564] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000320: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.743653] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000330: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.743743] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000340: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.743833] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000350: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.743930] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000360: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744042] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000370: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744137] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000380: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744224] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000390: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744307] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000003a0: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744392] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000003b0: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744475] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000003c0: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744559] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000003d0: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744651] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000003e0: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744740] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000003f0: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000001
[ 1412.744828] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000400: 0x00e04808, 0x00400000, 0x00001000, 0x00009b00
[ 1412.744914] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000410: 0x0000b8ac, 0x6fbb0b08, 0x0000b8ac, 0x6fbb0b08
[ 1412.745012] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000420: 0x0000b8ac, 0x6fbb0b08, 0x0000b8ac, 0x6fbb0b08
[ 1412.745109] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000430: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x000001cf, 0x000005f2
[ 1412.745438] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000440: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x08310301
[ 1412.745521] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000450: 0x00000001, 0x00008000, 0x00000000, 0x00000112
[ 1412.745605] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000460: 0x00000008, 0x00002620, 0x01000006, 0x00000000
[ 1412.745696] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000470: 0x80000000, 0x00000000, 0x10000000, 0x40010042
[ 1412.745785] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000480: 0x42000000, 0x7fffffff, 0x06000004, 0x7fffffff
[ 1412.745873] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000500: 0x00000008, 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.745959] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000590: 0x09900000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.746058] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000600: 0xffffffff, 0x00f80011, 0x00000000, 0x00001f04
[ 1412.746155] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000610: 0xffffffff, 0x00000000, 0x07c00004, 0x0461d800
[ 1412.746247] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000620: 0x00000040, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.746333] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000800: 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.746419] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000810: 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.746502] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000820: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000
[ 1412.746586] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000830: 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff
[ 1412.746671] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000840: 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff
[ 1412.746762] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000850: 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff
[ 1412.746850] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000860: 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000
[ 1412.746939] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000880: 0x00000135, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747026] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000890: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747122] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000008f0: 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747219] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000c00: 0x0000000a, 0x00000000, 0x00000003, 0x00000001
[ 1412.747311] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000c10: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x01480000
[ 1412.747397] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000c80: 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747480] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000ce0: 0x74373c02, 0x00000000, 0x00000148, 0x00040028
[ 1412.747565] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00000cf0: 0x00000000, 0x50000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747649] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001000: 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0xa0000003, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747733] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001010: 0x00010010, 0x00000003, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747824] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001400: 0x00000006, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.747912] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001440: 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001
[ 1412.748014] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001450: 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001
[ 1412.748103] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001460: 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001
[ 1412.748200] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001470: 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001
[ 1412.748296] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001480: 0x00000005, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.748392] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001800: 0x00000016, 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000
[ 1412.748481] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001840: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000200, 0x00000010
[ 1412.748565] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001850: 0x78c00000, 0x00000000, 0x00004000, 0x00010001
[ 1412.748650] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001860: 0x01000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.748734] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00001c00: 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.748818] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002000: 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.748909] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002010: 0x00000181, 0x00000001, 0x00780003, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749000] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002100: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749088] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002110: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749176] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002120: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749270] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002130: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749363] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002140: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749453] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002150: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749537] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002160: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749621] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002170: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749706] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002180: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749789] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002190: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749876] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000021a0: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.749965] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000021b0: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750053] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000021c0: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750140] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000021d0: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750234] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000021e0: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750332] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000021f0: 0x000c6635, 0x000c6635, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750423] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002200: 0x00000008, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750510] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002400: 0x00000012, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750594] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002450: 0x00000000, 0x73d4c000, 0x02000000, 0x00006000
[ 1412.750678] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002470: 0x00000000, 0x00000008, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750762] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000024c0: 0x08000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750846] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002800: 0x00000006, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.750938] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002c00: 0x00000006, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0000003f
[ 1412.751026] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002c10: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000010, 0x00000000
[ 1412.751114] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00002c20: 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.751202] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003000: 0x00000006, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0000003f
[ 1412.751300] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003600: 0xe0236400, 0x00171700, 0x00111100, 0x00000000
[ 1412.751395] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003610: 0x00171711, 0x00131311, 0x00171700, 0x00171711
[ 1412.751487] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003620: 0x80190009, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00032080
[ 1412.751572] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003630: 0x10000000, 0x30000000, 0x00001080, 0x00000000
[ 1412.751656] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003640: 0x00000005, 0x00000005, 0x00000020, 0x00000019
[ 1412.751743] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003650: 0x00000171, 0x61ff1bff, 0x05784100, 0x00000000
[ 1412.751827] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003660: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x000100af, 0x00000000
[ 1412.751912] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003670: 0x0000000a, 0xfefffff7, 0x03e8000f, 0x00310010
[ 1412.752014] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003680: 0x01011001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.752105] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003800: 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x0000000e, 0x0516028b
[ 1412.752196] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003810: 0x00000173, 0x00000074, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.752285] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003900: 0x00000000, 0x01000004, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.752382] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003c00: 0x00000302, 0x00000000, 0x00000014, 0x00000048
[ 1412.752477] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003c10: 0x00000005, 0x00000035, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.752580] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003c20: 0x00000005, 0x00000005, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.752667] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003c30: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x77ff1000
[ 1412.752751] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003c40: 0x00000000, 0x00000b00, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.752835] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003c50: 0x00000000, 0x00000008, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.752920] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003c80: 0x00000008, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.753004] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00003cc0: 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.753097] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004000: 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0x0007d566, 0x001aedea
[ 1412.753187] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004010: 0x00403020, 0x00235012, 0x00800440, 0x00400062
[ 1412.753277] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004020: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000010, 0x00000000
[ 1412.753363] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004030: 0x00000010, 0x00000030, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.753716] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004040: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x01080020, 0x00000000
[ 1412.753800] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004050: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00235010, 0x00401002
[ 1412.753884] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004060: 0x00404000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.753974] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004400: 0x00000006, 0x00000000, 0x00011080, 0x00009f80
[ 1412.754057] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004410: 0x00000000, 0x00000010, 0x00000060, 0x00000000
[ 1412.754144] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004420: 0x0000003d, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.754235] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004440: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000c05
[ 1412.754324] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004450: 0x0001033e, 0x00150016, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.754413] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004800: 0x08033bfe, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000020
[ 1412.754505] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004810: 0x00000000, 0x00000004, 0x07e003c8, 0x00000000
[ 1412.754598] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004820: 0x00000004, 0x00000000, 0xf0330000, 0x74373d50
[ 1412.754692] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004830: 0x00000000, 0x00000027, 0x00000027, 0x00000000
[ 1412.754779] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004840: 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x030e2200, 0x042afec8
[ 1412.754863] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004850: 0xffffac67, 0x01370148, 0x01000100, 0x00000000
[ 1412.754947] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004860: 0x01000004, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.755032] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004900: 0x00048405, 0x0000ce08, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.755116] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004910: 0x00000018, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.755206] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004c00: 0x200003fe, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.755295] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004c10: 0x00000015, 0x00000000, 0x00000006, 0x00000000
[ 1412.755383] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004c20: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000006
[ 1412.755468] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004c30: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0000005e, 0x0000005e
[ 1412.755564] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004c40: 0x00000000, 0x77ff1000, 0x00010020, 0x00000020
[ 1412.755658] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00004c50: 0x07fffe07, 0x00200fff, 0x00000000, 0x04080d0d
[ 1412.755749] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005000: 0x00009800, 0x80004000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.755834] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005010: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00010644
[ 1412.755918] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005020: 0xafb10014, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x40000020
[ 1412.756015] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005030: 0x00000000, 0x0000001d, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.756109] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005040: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00010e1e, 0x00000000
[ 1412.756203] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005200: 0x00000001, 0x00002000, 0x00000b50, 0xc0000000
[ 1412.756297] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005210: 0x00010000, 0x0001bf90, 0x00000000, 0x0001bfb0
[ 1412.756403] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005220: 0x0001bf90, 0xc0000000, 0x00010804, 0x00040000
[ 1412.756502] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005230: 0x00000000, 0xc0000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.756593] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005240: 0x00040000, 0x0001bf90, 0x0001bfb0, 0x00000000
[ 1412.756678] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005250: 0x0001bf90, 0x00000000, 0x0001bf90, 0x00000000
[ 1412.756764] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005260: 0x0001bf90, 0x00000000, 0x0001bf90, 0x00000000
[ 1412.756861] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005270: 0xc0000000, 0x00000b50, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.756956] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005600: 0x168414e4, 0x00100506, 0x02000010, 0x00000008
[ 1412.757047] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005610: 0xfebf0004, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.757140] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005620: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x02811028
[ 1412.757233] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005630: 0x00000000, 0x00000048, 0x00000000, 0x0000010a
[ 1412.757325] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005640: 0x00f46003, 0xfff4798e, 0xc0034001, 0x64002008
[ 1412.757423] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005650: 0x0081cc05, 0xfee08004, 0x00000000, 0x00004021
[ 1412.757528] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005660: 0x006c5009, 0xfaebf50b, 0xf1000298, 0x76180000
[ 1412.757639] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005670: 0x000010f2, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.757749] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005680: 0x0a000064, 0x0a000064, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.757860] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000056b0: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x05784100
[ 1412.757961] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000056c0: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0000000e, 0x00020010
[ 1412.758066] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000056d0: 0x00008fa1, 0x00102100, 0x00074c11, 0x10110040
[ 1412.758152] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000056f0: 0x0000001f, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.758241] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005700: 0x13c10001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00062031
[ 1412.758326] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005710: 0x00000000, 0x00002000, 0x000000a0, 0x00000000
[ 1412.758415] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005730: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x16010002
[ 1412.758500] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005750: 0x800000ff, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.758586] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005760: 0x16c10003, 0xfebb0b08, 0xb8ac6fff, 0x00010004
[ 1412.758678] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005770: 0x00000000, 0x0007810e, 0x00000001, 0x2c0c3c0e
[ 1412.758774] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005780: 0x3f062304, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xffffffff
[ 1412.758867] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005800: 0x00000000, 0x04000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.758958] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005860: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x000000c8
[ 1412.759050] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005900: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759139] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005980: 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759241] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00005a00: 0x00012001, 0x00000000, 0x00010000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759355] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00006000: 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759465] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00006800: 0x04130034, 0x2408d082, 0x01009209, 0x519abf83
[ 1412.759561] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00006810: 0x81020000, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759652] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00006890: 0x00000000, 0x8001b000, 0x000001ef, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759739] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000068a0: 0x00000000, 0x00010001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759825] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x000068b0: 0x00000004, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
[ 1412.759914] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00007000: 0x00000108, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x000000c0
[ 1412.760027] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00007010: 0x0a000064, 0x57479a70, 0x00570081, 0x68848353
[ 1412.760178] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00007020: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xaf000406, 0x00000000
[ 1412.760307] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00007030: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x000100e0, 0x00000000
[ 1412.760476] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0x00007500: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0000008b, 0x00000000
[ 1412.760614] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0: Host status block [00000001:0000000e:(0000:0009:0000):(0009:0001)]
[ 1412.760750] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: 0: NAPI info [00000004:00000004:(0001:0000:01ff):0000:(00c8:0000:0000:0000)]
[ 1412.862758] tg3 0000:02:00.0: tg3_stop_block timed out, ofs=1400 enable_bit=2
[ 1412.884691] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is down
```

Here is some other possibly relevant information:

```
fmillion@sql2:~$ sudo lspci -v

...

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
        Memory at febf0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [40] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [60] Vendor Specific Information: Len=6c <?>
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [cc] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number b8-ac-6f-ff-fe-bb-0b-08
        Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: tg3
        Kernel modules: tg3
```

```
fmillion@sql2:~$ uname -a
Linux sql2 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
fmillion@sql2:~$ ip -s link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    239192     3964     0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    239192     3964     0       0       0       0
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ac:6f:bb:0b:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    2110       8        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    332        1        0       0       0       0
```

```
fmillion@sql2:~$ sudo ethtool enp2s0
Settings for enp2s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                            drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
        Link detected: no
```

Is there any steps I can take to get the network driver working, save for possibly messing with a custom kernel?

Comment: You can try installing the older kernel, but there are other differences that can cause this to happen, such as blacklisted modules or different mappings for which PCIDs should use which modules.